# Passenger 5.2 + apache + redmine : breaking changes

Tags: apache, passenger, redmine

PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot is removed.
PassengerAppRoot can no longer be used...

ok, but in practice, how to adapt the apache configuration files?

Thanks in advance for any practical guideline.

Example: 
Here is the current content of my  /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine.conf file...

```
# fichier destiné à utiliser redmine via le port 3000 en http
<VirtualHost *:3000>
  # rendre appel possible via tripkit.dlinkddns.com:3000
  ServerName tripkit.dlinkddns.com
  # rendre appel possible via www.tripkit.dlinkddns.com:3000
  ServerAlias www.tripkit.dlinkddns.com
  # rendre appel possible via localhost:3000
  ServerAlias localhost
  # follow simlinks home/www-data pour qu'apache2 puisse accéder à la version de  redmine en pointant sur redmine
  <Directory /home/www-data>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  # Passenger a aussi un filtre pour bloquer les simlinks, bloqué par défaut. Il faut le débloquer.
  PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
  # positionner apache dans les répertoires adhoc
  DocumentRoot /home/www-data/redmine/public
  PassengerAppRoot /home/www-data/redmine
  # définir les users pour ouvrir les accès aux répertoires www-data (sinon, on se retrouve avec le répertoire su user qui a fait linstallation!)
  PassengerDefaultUser www-data
  PassengerUser www-data
  PassengerDefaultGroup www-data
  PassengerGroup www-data
  PassengerDefaultGroup www-data
  # Relax Apache security settings on public
  <Directory /home/www-data/redmine/public>
    AllowOverride all
    # MultiViews must be turned off.
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  # Relax Apache security settings on Gemfile and Gemfile.lock
  <Directory /home/www-data/redmine>
    <Files Gemfile>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    <Files Gemfile.lock>
        Require all granted
    </Files>  
  </Directory>
  # adresse de rails
  RailsBaseURI /home/www-data/redmine/bin
  # si on veut un log specifique pour débugger les erreurs specifiques à passenger, activer la ligne ci-dessous.
  # sinon, elles seront dans /var/log/apache2/errors.log
  # PassengerLogFile /var/log/apache2/error_passenger.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Not sure what are you asking...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache passenger stopped work after upgrade passenger from 5.1.12 to 5.20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48623209/apache-passenger-stopped-work-after-upgrade-passenger-from-5-1-12-to-5-20)